# SQL Server 2008 R2 installation on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-10

SQL Server setup is showing the following error, I don't understand this, please help me.

[image]

Comment: I can't find evidence that SQL Server 2008 R2 is supported by Microsoft on Windows 10 anywhere on the web.  SQL Server 2016 however, is supported on Windows 10 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx.  Does that help?

Comment: [SQL Server 2008 R2 is not supported on Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2681562), although [apparently](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112206/maintaining-sql-server-2008-r2-on-windows-10) you should still be able to install it.

Comment: Could [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/957453) or [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a94fcca0-b9cc-4287-90fe-f3151ef997ab/sql-server-2008-r2-installation?forum=sqlgetstarted) be the problem?

Comment: thank you, now i understand what was the problem.

Comment: So what was the actual problem?